# How do I make a simple idle bobbing motion/animation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Prepare to see some really ugly code.

So essentially what I want to do is create a simple up and down bobbing motion for a 3d object in unity, that gets faster on its descent, and then slows back down on the ascent. The code I have below achieves this effect, but I know there has to be a better, more elegant way of doing it, I just can't find one.

```
public class IdleAnimation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotSpeed = 3.0f;
    public float minimum = 0.1f;
    public float maximum = 0.5f;
    public float yPos;

    public float bounceProgress = 0;
    public float initBounceSpeed = 0.001f;
    private float bounceSpeed;
    public float bounceAcc = 0.002f;
    public float dir = 1;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        bounceSpeed = initBounceSpeed;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //interpolates between the minimum and maximum based on the bounceProgress
        yPos = Mathf.Lerp(minimum, maximum, bounceProgress);
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, yPos, transform.position.z);

        //bounceProgress increases/decreases by the bounceSpeed
        bounceProgress += bounceSpeed * dir;
        //bounceSpeed increases/decreases by the bounceAcc
        bounceSpeed += bounceAcc * dir;

        //once the bounceProgress reaches 1, the direction reverses
        //note that it will be going at maximum speed here
        if(bounceProgress > 1)
            dir = -1;
        //once the bounceProgress reaches 0, the direction reverses
        //note that it will be going at minimum speed here
        else if (bounceProgress < 0)
        {
            dir = 1;
            //resets bounceSpeed to avoid going into a negativeSpeed
            bounceSpeed = initBounceSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like there has to be a better way of doing this utilizing Mathf.PingPong or Mathf.SmoothStep or something like that, I just can't figure it out. Any and all advice is appreciated

Comment: You are describing an arc. Arcs are best represented with trigonometric functions. Have you considered using `Mathf.Sin`?

Comment: I didn't think about that. that seems like its the right answer. I'm going to try it out now

Comment: @Abion47 absolutely incredible, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to some help from Abion47 I was able to figure out that Mathf.Sin was exactly what I needed.

```
public class IdleAnimation : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotSpeed = 3;
    private float minimum = 0.1f;
    private float maximum = 0.5f;

    private float yPos;
    private float bounceSpeed = 3;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float sinValue = Mathf.Sin(Time.time * bounceSpeed);

        yPos = Mathf.Lerp(maximum, minimum, Mathf.Abs(sinValue));
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, yPos, transform.position.z);

        //Rotate
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, Time.deltaTime * rotSpeed);

    }
```

Comment: Using `InverseLerp` like this would result in transform behavior that also slows as it reaches zero, which would be like an easing function whereas you said you wanted a bounce. In that case, I'd suggest instead using `Mathf.Abs(sinValue)` to produce a "bouncing" sine wave.

Comment: And as a nitpick, I'd say that doing `(1.0f + sinValue) / 2.0f` to map sine wave output to 0..1 would be more performant (and arguably idiomatic) than using `Mathf.InverseLerp` for the same purpose. That said, it's somewhat subjective and the performance gains would likely be negligible. Just food for thought.

Comment: yep, that makes more sense. I thought it didn't look right, but I thought I had just been looking at it too long. thanks